# what is the GTK# equivalent of a control from C#?

Tags: gtk#

I have recently transferred from C# to GTK# because my computer doesn't support C#. I am trying to write a program and i keep getting an error. does anyone know what the GTK# equivalent of a control is?

Answer (score 1):

The entire architecture is a bit different than most of the other C# UI libraries.  The closest equivalent to "Control" would likely be [Gtk.Widget](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtk.Widget), which is the (eventual) base class of most of the "controls" in GTK#.